# Linux Mint takes 18.2 Cinamon too much time to turn off

Tags: linux-mint, boot

Several days ago I installed Linux Mint 18.2 Cinamon "Sonya", everything works great and it's very fast! :)

But when I pressed the turn off button, it took over two minutes from pc to turn off. While it was "turning off" I got this messages:

```
[ 947.438205 ] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[ 9407.438770] ata8.00: failed command: STANDBY IMMEDIATE
[ 9407.439171] ata8.00: cmd e0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 23
[ 9407.439171]  res 40/00:00:00:01:80/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 9407.440220] ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 9417.450143] ata8: softreset failed (device not ready)
[ 9427.462115] ata8: softreset failed (device not ready)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible that a hard drive is starting to fail or (hopefully) you have a damaged cable. Check : [Are these SATA errors dangerous?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous)

Answer (score 0):

I had a machine start doing that. Linux Mint has a timeout on many processes of 90 seconds, and will hang that long before just killing them. It's hard to tell from what you have posted, so I can't really say which one is causing the delay. I can say in my case it was the CUPS browser hanging for some reason. Since I didn't need it, I disabled it, and shutting down went form minutes to seconds.

You can press escape when the logo shows during shutdown to get a bit of logging text. It will show which processes are hanging. Note that not all of them may actually be hung (especially encrypted storage) so much as they're waiting for the hung process(es) to time out before they can shut down.